# typo3 update 4.7 -> 6.2 - broken backend

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I've performed an update from typo3 4.7.20 to 6.2.15. The process worked fine and there were no critical errors while running the install tool.

The frontend looks fine but the backend is broken:[image]

I've removed all uncompatible extensions before I run the update. I've also checked all settings in the installationtool und deleted the temp/cache folder first.

I've got the feeling that the error is caused by the TemplaVoila! extension, I'm using v. 1.9.8. Firebug does not shows any error.

Does anyone had a similar problem and have already solved it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I recognize this problem from one of my own upgrades. Can you please logout from the back-end and add the html of the login screen to the issue?

Comment: I mean the full html output of `/typo3/`  when you're logged out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've added the html output!

Comment: That seems to be ok, you can remove the html output now. Can you list the content of `typo3conf/PackagesStates.php` now? Sorry kinda hard to debug this from here ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this one multiple times. More often it is because there is a broken TBE_STYLES. I suggest you look around for $TBE_STYLES in your typo3conf folder and disable it for the time being. Most likely it will be in the extTables.php or some other file which is included dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

seems BE is working, but you css does not got loaded.
check your 'web inspecter' to see if you get errors on loading CSS.

clear your cache (remove everything in typo3temp) and try again

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solved the problem. All included files ( CSS, JS, .. ) were successfully loaded. Clearing the typo3temp folder also didn't helped.